# Return the value of rows affected to ExecuteNonQuery when used cursor in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have used cursor in a stored procedure which gets data from xml to insert,delete or update the records based on the business rules.

when executed using `ExecuteNonQuery()`,it returns `-1` even though rows are affected.

Please let me know regarding this.

Thanks,
King

Comment: Questions like this do nobody any good without an example of your code please show all code that pertains to your question or issue at hand Showing the `Stored Proc` will help from guess work

Comment: Please give us more info. Some code example would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored proc?

Try `SET NOCOUNT OFF`

See this T-SQL [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

From *[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*;

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.**

IMO your problem fits one of these options.

I just say it based on *return value* of course. For getting more help from people, you should give people more information.